# How to use multiply arithmetic operator in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

How to use multiply operator in power apps, I have the following condition, first set to multiply is from text box and other two are based on dropdown selection, but the below code does not work

```
Textbox1'*Text('Dropdown1'.Selected.Value*'Dropdown2'.Selected.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should just work (see below)

[image]

I would recommend, however, being more explicit about using numbers for the operations. For example the TextInput control's default property is of type text, so we should use the [Value function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-value) to convert it to a number prior to multiplying it. Notice that this is done automatically in the previous example, but if there are errors (for example, if the value in the text input is not a number) you may get better error messages using a function explicitly.

[image]